# Test database connection before step initialization in Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: database-connection, pentaho, kettle

I am currently working on a transformation in Pentaho Kettle. I have numerous steps all depending on the same database connection. The username and password are provided by the user as parameters. If the wrong credentials are provided, every single step that is dependent on the database connection fails to initialize and logs a separate error about it. This results in a great wall of scary red text, that I am afraid will be quite hard to interpret for the intended end user of the transformation.

So, is there any way to test the database credentials before the other steps are initializing and then log a single informative error message if they are incorrect?

Comment: couldn't you define a job containing two transformations, in the first get the database connection parameters, test the connection and only move forward if connection was successful?

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek That is a smart workaround. Would prefer to have it all in one way, but if not possible your suggestion surely gets the job done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Check Db connections](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Check+Db+connections) step in PDI Job. Here you can easily give all the connections that you are using in the job. Finally based on the connection setting, you can define your logic flow.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Interesting! Did not know about that step - will test how it works and report back! Thank you!

Comment: Just realized that the step is only available in a job, not a transformation. I would prefer not to have to wrap my transformation in a job. But perhaps I will have to?

Comment: @Anders if there are multiple transformations and you might need to execute each ktr files, i prefer to wrap all the .ktr files into a single job. That's the main idea behind jobs, to wrap the ktr files all into one and to provide a overall logic flow. it becomes easier to handle files anyways !!! but in the end its upto your business requirement

Comment: There is only one one transformation, but with multiple steps generating errors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can create a job which will check the db connections first and then execute the transformation !!.